# Is coaxial cable an option for distances of around 150 m to transfer SDI digital signals

Tags: video, digital-recording, digital

Is coaxial cable an option for distances of around **150 m** to transfer SDI digital signals?

If coaxial cable can be considered an option for a distance of 150 m, is the **cost** of deploying coaxial cable, including any special connectors and amplifiers, larger than the cost of deploying **fiber** optic cables for the same distance of 150 m?

I know, this might be a very broad/generic question, but we are in the process of decision-making about our tech stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

300 Feet is about as far as you can take SDI or HD-SDI; before it needs to be reclocked. So no, 150 M is too far. Also the quality of cable; and if it's being run in parallel with other cables that cause interference can affect how long you can go.

You can reclock at the half way point using a distribution amplifier, and you'll lose 1 frame of sync for each time you reclock.

Your next best option is to run Fiber Optic; which you can run for 25 miles without having to deal with any signal loss issues.

Comment: Importantly to the cost question, you need to have power at the point where you reclock. The cost of installing a circuit in a typical major US city commercial building will be more than the cost of the equipment to run fiber for a small number of video signals. See [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21539/calculate-coaxial-cable-type-grade-to-transfer-digital-video-signals-to-a-known/21542) for links on maximum cable lengths.